# Search Youtube and return JSON

Tags: json, youtube

Is there a url I can use the search for 'foo' on YouTube, and return JSON with a list of videos?

Comment: Did you check their API?

Comment: Yes, can't find how to get JSON. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=foo gets XML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As their API docs clearly state, just add `?alt=json`:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=foo&alt=json

Answer (score 4):

The [YouTube JSON API Page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json) can help you out.

Some research on the API Page points out that http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=foo&alt=json is all you need...

Comment: If you cat get JSON from those urls, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

On latest update:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=SEARCHPARAMATER&maxResults=25&key=`key`

By using this URL you will be able to give the search parameter and get the desired JSON.

Answer (score 1):

[yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) can help you out.

```bash
yt-dlp --print-json ytsearch:'foo'
```

Then you could redirect the output of the command to a file, it would be the best option, you could also use the lib instead of the command line.